# Appending to a string macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a program that offers different functionality depending on compile time definitions. I defined `OPT_STRING` that holds all possible command line arguments (for use with `getopt_long`). I've been looking for a clever to change the definition of it depending on compile time definitions. I've came up with this:

```
#define OPT_STRING "haspvb"

#ifdef HAVE_WIFI
#define OPT_STRING OPT_STRING "mw" // => "haspvb" "mw"
#endif // HAVE_WIFI

#ifdef HAVE_IMEI
#define OPT_STRING OPT_STRING "i" // => "haspvb" "mw" "i" or "haspvb" "i"
#endif // HAVE_IMEI
```

However, this results in a compilation error:

```
error: "OPT_STRING" redefined
```

Is there some kind of "macro magic" to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "append" to a macro, it's simply not possible.

As a possible solution you could define *different* macros, and then use them together to define the final `OPT_STRING` macro:

```
#define OPT_STRING_BASE "haspvb"

#ifdef HAVE_WIFI
#define OPT_STRING_WIFI "mw"
#else
#define OPT_STRING_WIFI
#endif // HAVE_WIFI

#ifdef HAVE_IMEI
#define OPT_STRING_IMEI "i"
#else
#define OPT_STRING_IMEI
#endif // HAVE_IMEI

#define OPT_STRING (OPT_STRING_BASE OPT_STRING_WIFI OPT_STRING_IMEI)
```